# jaspersoft not install in eclipse Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, jaspersoft-studio

[image: Check Here Error of at the time of installing jasperfsoft studio]

how to run jasper Report in eclipse Ubuntu. and i try to install jasper soft studio in eclipse but it's not installing.. i don't know why.. 
  is there any restriction on jasper soft studio for install in eclipse Ubuntu ...??

Comment: If you use an older version of Eclipse, try to add the update site `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen` (and maybe `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon`) in _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_

Comment: Thanks for your #howlger replay but.  i use latest version of Eclipse. and in windows use same eclipse version but it's work... but not in Ubuntu....???

Comment: The error message says that [this file](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/mwe/updates/releases/2.9.0/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core_1.3.20.v201605261103.jar.pack.gz) can not be downloaded. Maybe, `download.eclipse.org` was temporarily unavailable (please retry) or you have to check your Eclipse proxy preferences.

Comment: Jasper Installed but when i run jasper report in jsp page that's time it's show below error... may be jar issue But jar use at my system as well as client system......
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/javaflow/bytecode/Continuable"

Comment: Great, I added my comment as answer (see below). Regarding the _NoClassDefFoundError_ problem: if [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527250/noclassdeffounderror-orgapachecommonsjavaflow) does not help, ask a separate question with more information about when and where exactly the problem occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **error** message says that **[this file](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/mwe/updates/releases/2.9.0/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core_1.3.20.v201605261103.jar.pack.gz) can not be downloaded**:

- Maybe, `download.eclipse.org` was temporarily unavailable: **please retry**
- If that does not help, check your Eclipse proxy settings: ***Window > Preferences: General > Network Connection***